# MOQ Excel File and write unit test

Tags: c#, moq, epplus, xunit

I have a webapi where one endpoint is an file upload. I am using moq and xunit (.netcore) to test my apis. While I am able to write my test case for others I am not sure how to do the same for my file. This upload expects excel file as the input, does some processing by reading the columns and rows of the excel worksheet and then returns back an Jarray to the UI.  Below is my api endpoint for file upload:

```
    [HttpPost("file/upload")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UploadData(IFormFile file)
    {
        JArray dataArray = new JArray();
        try
        {
            using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(file.OpenReadStream()))
            {
                ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[1];

                //Check if excel is empty.
                if (worksheet.Dimension == null)
                {
                    //throw error
                }
                else
                {
                    //Read from excel populate dataArray
                }                   
            }

            return Ok(dataArray);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return BadRequest(e.Message);
        }

    }
```

- How can I write Xunit test case for an excel file.
- How can I moq up an excel file and its contents.

FYI, I am using EPPlus OfficeOpenXml for my excel.

Comment: Usually you write some sort of wrapper and implement an interface. And this method should work with that interface while you passing mocked wrapper or original one.

Comment: There is no solution provided in that question